# Can't use __m128i in Cuda kernel

Tags: c++, cuda, intrinsics, nvcc

I am trying to compile a simple program that uses `__m128i` using cuda, but when I compile using nvcc (nvcc test.cu -o test) on Linux, I get `"__m128i" is a vector, which is not supported in device code`.
This is the program I am trying to compile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>

__global__ void hello(){
    printf("%d\n",threadIdx.x);
    __m128i x;

}
int main(){
   hello<<<3,3>>>();
}
```

When I type `nvcc --version`, I get `Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89`

I actually faced this problem on a larger scale trying to implement some cpp code using CUDA and this cpp code uses `__m128i`, and what I have shown is the simple version of the problem I am facing, so I am wondering if there is a way to use `__m128i` in a CUDA kernel, or some other alternative. Thanks

Comment: @TedLyngmo: That post talks about GNU C `__uint128_t` which is totally unrelated to `__m128i`, other than having the same size.  An SSE integer vector isn't a 128-bit integer type; the widest element size is `_mm_add_epi64`.  (Unless you're only using bitwise boolean operations, then element boundaries don't matter.)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: But `__m128i` isn't *a* 128-bit integer; it's a SIMD vector.  In GNU C, defined as `typedef long long __m128i __attribute__((vector_size(16), may_alias))`.  Having a scalar 128-bit integer type supported by CUDA wouldn't help you compile code that uses `__m128i` with intrinsics like `_mm_shuffle_epi32`, `_mm_add_epi32`, and so on (treating it as a vector of 4x 32-bit integers), or `_mm_minpos_epu16` (horizontal min and min-position of 16-bit unsigned elements), or other SSE hardware operations.  You can't use `__m128i` as a single 128-bit integer, so that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah ... now I get what you're saying. :) Sorry for the confusion. Removing comment.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if there is a way to use `__m128i` in a CUDA kernel ...

There is not. CUDA has [native 128 bit integer types](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#built-in-vector-types) which meet the same alignment properties as `__m128i`, but a host vector type is not supported.

> or some other alternative

As noted above, there are 16 byte aligned types which can be used to load and store data, but there is no native 128 bit SIMD intrinsic support in NVIDIA GPUs. Those [SIMD instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simd-video) which exist are limited to 32 bit types.

---

CPU SIMD is done with short vectors like 128-bit `__m128i`. GPU SIMD is done across warps, and not usually software-visible in the same way as `__m128i` CPU SIMD, you just write it as scalar code.

Code manually vectorized with `__m128i` can't be compiled for a GPU.  If it has a scalar fallback version, use that, e.g. `#undef __SSE2__`.

(CUDA SIMD within 32-bit chunks lets you get more use out of the 32-bit wide ALUs in each GPU execution unit if you have narrow data, like pairs of 16-bit integers, or 4x 8-bit integers.  So if your SSE intrinsics code uses `_mm_add_epi8`, you might still benefit from manual vectorization in CUDA with its 4x 8-bit operations instead of 16x 8-bit.)

Comment: I know you do, I should have made that an edit to your community-wiki answer because it was intended for the benefit of future readers who don't understand that CPU and GPU expose SIMD differently to the programmer.  update: Edited.